# Programming language for self-modifying code?

Tags: programming-languages, dynamic-languages, self-modifying

- I am recently thinking about writing **self-modifying programs**, I think it may be powerful and fun. So I am currently looking for a language that allows modifying a program's own code easily.
- I read about **C#** (as a way around) and the ability to compile and execute code in runtime, but that is too painful.
- I am also thinking about **assembly**. It is easier there to change running code but it is not very powerful (very raw).

**Can you suggest a powerful language or feature that supports modifying code in runtime?**

#### Example

This is what I mean by modifying code in runtime:

```
  Start:
  a=10,b=20,c=0;
  label1: c=a+b;
  ....
  label1= c=a*b;
  goto label1;
```

and may be building a list of instructions:

```
  code1.add(c=a+b);
  code1.add(c=c*(c-1));
  code1. execute();
```

Comment: Do you want to compile/execute code at runtime, or do you want to modify the executable itself while it's loaded into memory:  those are two *very* different things.  (Usually *"self-modifying"* means the second)

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: I am interested in the second.. The first is meant if the second is impossible or not available ...

Comment: I used to think about self-modifying code a lot. I've never found much use for it after I learned about function pointers and object oriented languages.  Do you have any real-world use for this?

Comment: @aaaa bbbb: I want to learn such a language to discover real-world use of it!

Comment: dynamic programming is a family of minimzation/maximization techniques. It is unrelated to dynamic languages/typing. Kinda a nomenclature problem...

Comment: @Paul Nathan: sorry I will fix it

Comment: Redcode (http://vyznev.net/corewar/guide.html) , many of the best warriors are self modifing...

Comment: In interpreting languages it is far from rocket science - build you program as generator of code and eval()-it.
Things are far more interesting and complex in compiled languages. You'll have to know underlying layer (assembly or specific byte-code) to manipulate it.

I'm not sure but maybe alternative are worth mentioning - e.g. - putting logic into DLLs (or COM servers) and constructing the program flow as the series of corresponding invokations.

PS: Aren't you thinking of polymorphic viruses? you can get pretty much interesting and difficult stuff on that matter by googling

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Malbolge](http://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge.shtml) would be a good place to start. Every instruction is self-modifying, and it's a lot of fun(*) to play with.

(*) Disclaimer: May not actually be fun.

Comment: The programming language where it took a few years for a person to write hello world... Oh wait, the hello world program was generated by a computer.  Have fun lulz.

Answer (score 24):

I highly recommend Lisp. Lisp data can be read and exec'd as code. Lisp code can be written out as data.

It is considered one of the canonical self-modifiable languages.

Example list(data):

```
'(+ 1 2 3)
```

or, calling the data as code

```
(eval '(+ 1 2 3))
```

runs the + function.

You can also go in and edit the members of the lists on the fly.

edit:

I wrote a program to dynamically generate a program and evaluate it on the fly, then report to me how it did compared to a baseline(div by 0 was the usual report, ha).

Answer (score 16):

Every answer so far is about reflection/runtime compilation, but in the comments you mentioned you're interested in actual [self-modifying code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code) - code that modifies itself in-memory.

There is no way to do this in C#, Java, or even (portably) in C - that is, you cannot modify the loaded in-memory binary using these languages.

In general, the only way to do this is with assembly, and it's highly processor-dependent.  In fact, it's highly operating-system dependent as well: to protect against [polymorphic viruses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code), most modern operating systems *(including Windows XP+, Linux, and BSD)* enforce [W^X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX), meaning you have to [go through some trouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28VS.85%29.aspx) to write polymorphic executables in those operating systems, for the ones that allow it at all.

It may be possible in some interpreted languages to have the program modify its own source-code while it's running.  Perl, <strike>Python</strike> *(see [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ByteplayDoc))*, and every implementation of Javascript I know of do not allow this, though.

Comment: You have a good point. Depending on how you look at it, C# / other .NET flavours / Java use bytecode instead of proper assembly, but the issue stands.

Comment: I should add that, if you were to do it the slightly roundabout and hacky way of iteratively issuing source code to a compiler, running the binary, and then having that binary in turn modify the source code to re-issue it to the compiler... That would (effectively) have read-write access to the program's code, even though the read-write turnaround time is bad.

Comment: Although I agree with the gist of the sentiment, I would suggest the possibility (in Python for example: http://geofft.mit.edu/blog/sipb/73) of directly alterering generated/running bytecode (which conceptually then doesn't differ much from doing the same with assembly).

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I find it quite strange that you find assembly easier to handle than C#. I find it even stranger that you think that assembly isn't as powerful: you can't get any more powerful than raw machine language. Anyway, to each his/her own.

C# has great reflection services, but if you have an aversion to that.. If you're really comfortable with C or C++, you could always write a program that writes C/C++ and issues it to a compiler. This would only be viable if your solution doesn't require a quick self-rewriting turn-around time (on the order of tens of seconds or more).

Javascript and Python both support reflection as well. If you're thinking of learning a new, fun programming language that's powerful but not massively technically demanding, I'd suggest Python.

Comment: I see nothing strange here.  Assembly is about as simple as you can get, while C# is huge and complex -- and I say this as someone who's been writing C# for a couple years!  As for power, I think in programming it usually means something like "expressive ability" or "abstraction-building ability" (obviously the literal meaning of "power" is useless here!), and assembly language is exceptionally poor at that.

Comment: @Reinderien: I mean in terms of changing existing code, assembly is easier than C#... 
Also in terms of readability and writability, assembly is less powerful...

Comment: I think asm is much easier than C# or Java. It is very straightforward and uncomplicated.

Comment: I agree that C# is huge and complex. That being said, compare the number of lines of code needed to open a file in C# versus assembly. For modern programming tasks, assembly is simply not an option. For sub-sub-subtasks that require heavy optimization, perhaps.

As for power, I essentially meant the number of things that you're allowed to directly manipulate. This isn't always helpful, however; it's like being given a pile of carbon and being told to build a dog.

Assembly can get very tricky to modify on-the-fly - you essentially have to act as a compiler. You need to do all the addressing.

Comment: @Ken @Reinderien @Paul: Assembly is harder than C#. **Period**. As hard as _effective_ C#? Maybe not. **Effective** assembly is **certainly** more hard than effective C#, though. You have to master your architecture, take into account increased cyclomatic complexity, caching, pipelining, interrupts, and possibly completely redesign your entire algorithm when the requirements change in order to make it as efficient as possible (to save registers, align some data, fix some ILP, etc), and If at hardware level: control the CPU (MSRs, TLB, Page Tables, I/O, control registers, etc).

Comment: @Longpoke: How is that different from mastering the C# semantics and the *gigantic* library packages and their different versions?

Comment: @Paul: Show me an assembly IDE with code completion and embedded documentation. The difference is that to make an effective C# application, you need to learn a very small subset of very well-documented libraries with oodles of examples. To make an effective assembly application, you need to drink from the firehose and understand the architecture from the bottom up, arcane abbreviations, electrical engineering issues and all.

Comment: @Reinderien: Honestly, I've used C# and assembly and I don't see a significant difference. I can get the job done in either.

Comment: Longpoke: For a given task, an assembly program to do the same thing will be more complex than a C# program to do that task.  But learning to write assembly is far simpler than learning to write C#.  (Saying "Period" in bold text doesn't make your argument any stronger.)  Most of the things you mention (caching, pipelining, etc.) can be ignored in assembly, or taken into account in C#, too.

Comment: @Ken: Why do you need to use assembly if you aren't using the full bleeding edge of it (or writing a compiler)? If you aren't pushing it to the limits, the compiler is going to **murder** you.

Answer (score 10):

May I suggest [Python](http://www.python.org/), a nice very high-level dynamic language which has rich introspection included (and by e.g. usage of `compile`, `eval` or `exec` permits a form of self-modifying code). A very simple example based upon your question:

```
def label1(a,b,c):
    c=a+b
    return c

a,b,c=10,20,0    
print label1(a,b,c) # prints 30

newdef= \
"""
def label1(a,b,c):
    c=a*b
    return c
"""
exec(newdef,globals(),globals())

print label1(a,b,c) # prints 200
```

Note that in the code sample above `c` is only altered in the function scope.

Answer (score 10):

[**Common Lisp**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) was designed with this sort of thing in mind.  You could also try [Smalltalk](http://squeak.org/), where using reflection to modify running code is not unknown.

In both of these languages you are likely to be replacing an entire function or an entire method, not a single line of code.  Smalltalk methods tend to be more fine-grained than Lisp functions, so that may be a good place to begin.

Answer (score 7):

Many languages allow you to [eval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval) code at runtime.

- Lisp
- Perl
- Python
- PHP
- Ruby
- Groovy (via GroovyShell)

Answer (score 4):

In high-level languages where you compile and execute code at run-time, it is not really self-modifying code, but dynamic class loading.  Using inheritance principles, you can replace a class Factory and change application behavior at run-time.

Only in assembly language do you really have true self-modification, by writing directly to the code segment.  But there is little practical usage for it.  If you like a challenge, write a self-encrypting, maybe polymorphic virus.  That would be fun.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes, although *very* rarely do self-modifying code in Ruby.

Sometimes you have a method where you don't really know whether the data you are using (e.g. some lazy cache) is properly initialized or not. So, you have to check at the beginning of your method whether the data is properly initialized and then maybe initialize it. But you really only have to do that initialization once, but you check for it every single time.

So, sometimes I write a method which does the initialization and then replaces itself with a version that doesn't include the initialization code.

```
class Cache
  def [](key)
    @backing_store ||= self.expensive_initialization

    def [](key)
      @backing_store[key]
    end

    @backing_store[key]
  end
end
```

But honestly, I don't think that's worth it. In fact, I'm embarrassed to admit that I have never actually benchmarked to see whether that *one* conditional actually makes any difference. (On a modern Ruby implementation with an aggressively optimizing profile-feedback-driven JIT compiler probably not.)

Note that, depending on how you *define* "self-modifying code", this may or may not be what you want. You *are* replacing some part of the *currently* executing program, so …

EDIT: Now that I think about it, that optimization doesn't make much sense. The expensive initialization is only executed once anyway. The only thing that modification avoids, is the conditional. It would be better to take an example where the check *itself* is expensive, but I can't think of one.

However, I thought of a cool example of self-modifying code: the [Maxine JVM](http://Labs.Oracle.Com/projects/maxine/). Maxine is a Research VM (it's technically not actually *allowed* to be called a "JVM" because its developers don't run the compatibility testsuites) written completely in Java. Now, there are plenty of JVMs written in itself, but Maxine is the only one I know of that also *runs* in itself. This is extremely powerful. For example, the JIT compiler can JIT compile itself to adapt it to the type of code that it is JIT compiling.

A very similar thing happens in the [Klein VM](http://KleinVM.SourceForge.Net/) which is a VM for the Self Programming Language.

In both cases, the VM can optimize and recompile *itself* at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote Python class Code that enables you to add and delete new lines of code to the object, print the code and excecute it. Class Code shown at the end.

Example: if the x == 1, the code changes its value to x = 2 and then deletes the whole block with the conditional that checked for that condition.

```
#Initialize Variables
x = 1

#Create Code
code = Code()
code + 'global x, code' #Adds a new Code instance code[0] with this line of code => internally             code.subcode[0]
code + "if x == 1:"     #Adds a new Code instance code[1] with this line of code => internally code.subcode[1]
code[1] + "x = 2"       #Adds a new Code instance 0 under code[1] with this line of code => internally code.subcode[1].subcode[0]
code[1] + "del code[1]" #Adds a new Code instance 0 under code[1] with this line of code => internally code.subcode[1].subcode[1]
```

After the code is created you can print it:

```
#Prints
print "Initial Code:"
print code
print "x = " + str(x)
```

Output:

```
Initial Code:

global x, code
if x == 1:
    x = 2
    del code[1]

x = 1
```

Execute the cade by calling the object: code()

```
print "Code after execution:"
code() #Executes code
print code
print "x = " + str(x)
```

Output 2:

```
Code after execution:

global x, code

x = 2
```

As you can see, the code changed the variable x to the value 2 and deleted the whole if block. This might be useful to avoid checking for conditions once they are met. In real-life, this case-scenario could be handled by a coroutine system, but this self modifying code experiment is just for fun.

```
class Code:

    def __init__(self,line = '',indent = -1):

        if indent < -1:
            raise NameError('Invalid {} indent'.format(indent))

        self.strindent = ''
        for i in xrange(indent):
            self.strindent = '    ' + self.strindent

        self.strsubindent = '    ' + self.strindent

        self.line = line
        self.subcode = []
        self.indent = indent


    def __add__(self,other):

        if other.__class__ is str:
            other_code = Code(other,self.indent+1)
            self.subcode.append(other_code)
            return self

        elif other.__class__ is Code:
            self.subcode.append(other)
            return self

    def __sub__(self,other):

        if other.__class__ is str:
            for code in self.subcode:
                if code.line == other:
                    self.subcode.remove(code)
                    return self


        elif other.__class__ is Code:
            self.subcode.remove(other)


    def __repr__(self):
        rep = self.strindent + self.line + '\n'
        for code in self.subcode: rep += code.__repr__()
        return rep

    def __call__(self):
        print 'executing code'
        exec(self.__repr__())
        return self.__repr__()


    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if key.__class__ is str:
                for code in self.subcode:
                    if code.line is key:
                        return code
        elif key.__class__ is int:
            return self.subcode[key]

    def __delitem__(self,key):
        if key.__class__ is str:
            for i in range(len(self.subcode)):
                code = self.subcode[i]
                if code.line is key:
                    del self.subcode[i]
        elif key.__class__ is int:
            del self.subcode[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Maple (the computer algebra language).  Unlike those many answers above which use compiled languages which only allow you to create and link in **new** code at run-time, here you can honest-to-goodness modify the code of a currently-running program.  (Ruby and Lisp, as indicated by other answerers, also allow you to do this; probably Smalltalk too).

Actually, it used to be standard in Maple that most library functions were small stubs which would load their 'real' self from disk on first call, and then self-modify themselves to the loaded version.  This is no longer the case as the library loading has been virtualized.

As others have indicated: you need an interpreted language with strong reflection and reification facilities to achieve this.

I have written an automated normalizer/simplifier for Maple code, which I proceeded to run on the whole library (including itself); and because I was not too careful in all of my code, the normalizer did modify itself.  I also wrote a [Partial Evaluator](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~carette/publications/scp_MaplePE.pdf) (recently accepted by SCP) called [MapleMIX - available on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/maplemix/) - but could not quite apply it fully to itself (that wasn't the design goal).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Java ? Java 6 has a [compiler API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html), so you can write code and compile it within the Java VM.

Answer (score 0):

In [Lua](http://www.lua.org), you can "hook" existing code, which allows you to attach arbitrary code to function calls. It goes something like this:

```
local oldMyFunction = myFunction
myFunction = function(arg)
    if arg.blah then return oldMyFunction(arg) end
    else
        --do whatever
    end
end
```

You can also simply plow over functions, which sort of gives you self modifying code.

Answer (score 0):

Dlang's LLVM implementation contains the @dynamicCompile and @dynamicCompileConst function attributes, allowing you to compile according to the native host's the instruction set at compile-time, and change compile-time constants in runtime through recompilation.

https://forum.dlang.org/thread/bskpxhrqyfkvaqzoospx@forum.dlang.org