# Is it possible to write self-modifying PowerShell scripts?

Tags: powershell, self-modifying

Is it possible to write self-modifying PowerShell scripts?

Suppose I have a script named `foo.ps1`:

```
"Write-Host `"Goodbye world`"" | Set-Content "foo.ps1"
Write-Host "Hello world"
```

This script prints out `Hello world`. What techniques could I use to get it to print out `Goodbye world`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it does not make sense, after you have modified a script, you need to re-dotsource it in order to get new statments.

This script changes itself three times:

```
Write-Host "Hello world"
"Write-Host `"Goodbye world`"" | Set-Content "foo.ps1"
. .\foo.ps1
"Write-Host `"Is really useful?`"" | Set-Content "foo.ps1"
. .\foo.ps1
```

and prints:

```
Hello World
Goodbye World
Is really useful?
```

Another possibility is to write a script which accepts as input parameters script blocks.

Comment: The example script I provided is trivial and contrived; there are lots of potential uses for self-modifying code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516688/what-are-the-uses-of-self-modifying-code). Your idea to dot-source the script is one answer to my question. I'm curious if there are other techniques for changing a script as it runs.

Comment: You asked for a self-modifying script. There is no other ways to load new data in the current working session, than dot-source.

Comment: Powershell is not really the proper language here. You might be interested in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057487/self-modifying-code).

Comment: You could have some kind of master Driver script, that is kicked off by the user. It then calls a subscript and dot sources it.. That script could modify itself and then send a return code that it should be reran and re-dot sourced. As stated above, PowerShell isn't really build for these kinds of lofty concepts in mind.

Comment: There's definitely uses for things like this. I'm trying to use it in nuget package manager (except it isn't self-modifying per se - it updates itself and then re-invokes with an 'ok I'm updated' argument). I haven't solved how to do this properly, though. :(

Comment: It can be useful for persisting settings the next time you run the script. i.e. 
if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($projPath))
{
$projPath = Read-Host -Prompt "Where is the project file?"
}
Now we can save that in the script so next time we don't need to ask. (sorry, comments are not meant for code)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you an however I would be there is a better way to do what you and to accomplish.

```
C:(...)WindowsPowerShell >.\foo.ps1
Hello world
C:(...)WindowsPowerShell >.\foo.ps1
Goodbye world
C:(...)WindowsPowerShell >
```

Comment: I would like to my script to be called *once* from the command line. With that in mind, you are basically suggesting that my script call itself after modifying itself.